# How to get data from MySQL with in Two Different Dates in android and display in Multi Column ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am passing three(customer name, Start date and End date) values to PHP file but the Problem behind, I con't pass the Three values at the time only one value(customer name) moved to PHP file.And how to display date in MULTI COLUMN LISTVIEW

java file:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.customer_repo);

    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    setCurrentDateOnView();
    addListenerOnButton();

    cus_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);//customer spinner
    created_date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    created_date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate2);

    //spinner for customer name
    cus_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_custo_report, R.id.txt, listItems);
    cus_name.setAdapter(adapter);
    cus_name.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(adapter, R.layout.custo_rep_nothingselect, this));


    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loadbtn);
    assert submit != null;
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            cus_names = cus_name.getSelectedItem().toString();
            createddate = created_date1.getText().toString();
            created_date = created_date2.getText().toString();
            String url_server = "http://192.168.1.13:8090/Vaari_services/getCustomerReportData.php";
            new BackgroundTask_Asycn().execute(url_server);
        }
    });
}


// Class with extends AsyncTask class
//product stock one
private class BackgroundTask_Asycn  extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    // Required initialization
    private final HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    private String Content;
    private String Error = null;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Customer_Repo.this);
    String cus_name ="";
    String created_date1 ="";
    String created_date2 ="";
    int sizeData = 0;
    TextView pro_stock1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    Spinner customerName = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView createddate1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    TextView createddate2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate2);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.
        //Start Progress Dialog (Message)

        Dialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        Dialog.show();

        try{
            // Set Request parameter product one
            cus_name +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("cus_name", "UTF-8") + "="+customerName.getSelectedItem();
            //created_date1 +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date1", "UTF-8") + "="+createddate1.getText();
            //created_date2 +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date2", "UTF-8") + "="+createddate2.getText();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Call after onPreExecute method
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        /************ Make Post Call To Web Server ***********/
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        // Send data
        try
        {
            // Defined URL  where to send data
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            // Send POST data request
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(cus_name);
            //wr.write(created_date1);
            //wr.write(created_date2);
            wr.flush();
            // Get the server response
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            // Read Server Response
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Append server response in string
                sb.append(line + "");
            }
            // Append Server Response To Content String
            Content = sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Error = ex.getMessage();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        // NOTE: You can call UI Element here.

        // Close progress dialog
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if (Error != null) {

            pro_stock1.setText("Output : "+Error);

        } else {

            // Show Response Json On Screen (activity)
            pro_stock1.setText( Content );

            /****************** Start Parse Response JSON Data *************/

            String OutputData = "";
            JSONObject jsonResponse;

            try {

                /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
                jsonResponse = new JSONObject(Content);


                /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
                /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("customer_repo");

                /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

                int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();

                for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++)
                {
                    /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                    /******* Fetch node values **********/
                    String Stock1 = jsonChildNode.optString("created_date").toString();
                    String Stock2 = jsonChildNode.optString("order_no").toString();
                    String Stock3 = jsonChildNode.optString("product").toString();
                    OutputData += Stock1 + Stock2 + Stock3;


                }
                /****************** End Parse Response JSON Data *************/

                //Show Parsed Output on screen (activity)
                pro_stock1.setText( OutputData );

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here is the problem start , How to pass the what i have to make. if there is any options

```
cus_name +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("cus_name", "UTF-8") + "="+customerName.getSelectedItem();
//created_date1 +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date1", "UTF-8") + "="+createddate1.getText();
//created_date2 +="&" + URLEncoder.encode("created_date2", "UTF-8") + "="+createddate2.getText();
```

and this is right way

```
    wr.write(cus_name);
   //wr.write(created_date1);
   //wr.write(created_date2);
```

XML file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#282828"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#282828"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="CUSTOMER ORDER REPORT"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#00aa55"
                    android:textSize="30dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </TableRow>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="1dp"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:text="FROM DATE"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/datepicker_btn"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="TO DATE"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvDate2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="2dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/loadbtn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/btnbg"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="LOAD"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </TableRow>
        </LinearLayout>

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- table format-->
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/colorCell">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="ORDER DATE"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="ORDER NO"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.5"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="PRODUCT NAME"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="ORDER QTY"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED QTY"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="SUPPLIED DATE"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="BALANCE QTY"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_customername"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="@null" />
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

PHP file:

```
    <?php
    require "db_config.php";

    $cus_name= $_POST["cus_name"];
    $created_date1= $_POST['created_date1'];
    $created_date2= $_POST['created_date2'];

    $sql="select oc.created_date,oc.order_no,ot.product,ot.order_qty,ot.qty_supply as Supplied_qty,ot.sup_date as issue_date,ot.bal_qty from order_creation oc inner join order_tran ot on oc.order_no=ot.orderno where oc.cus_name='".$cus_name."' and convert(datetime,ot.sup_date,104) between convert(datetime,'".$created_date1."') and convert(datetime, '".$created_date2."') and ot.product is not null order by ot.product,oc.order_no,ot.bal_qty desc";

    $stmt=sqlsrv_query($conn,$sql );
    if($stmt===false) 
    {
        die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
    }
    while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) 
    {
      $json['customer_repo'][]=$row;
    }
    sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
    echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but your PHP code is open for an SQL injection attack. You might want to read up on how to avoid those before you let that code run on a public server.

Comment: where is your AsyncTask ?? You are not getting NetworkOnMainThread ??

Comment: Okay Thank you Sir, I have to Work out for that later(before going to public)

Comment: I don't  use AsyncTask , i don't know how to modify the code to AsyncTask. @jankigadhiya

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Data model class instead of Hashamap for Dataset.

```
public class CustomerData {
    String createdAt;
    String orderNo;

    public CustomerData(String createdAt, String orderNo) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
        this.orderNo = orderNo;
    }

    public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public String getOrderNo() {
        return orderNo;
    }
}
```

Then modify your code like this

```
 public void ShowData() {
// listView1
    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_customername);

    Spinner cus_name = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    TextView created_date1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    TextView created_date2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate2);


    String url = "http://192.168.1.13:8090/Vaari_services/getCustomerReportData.php";

    // Paste Parameters
    //List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    new GetCustomerDataTask().execute(url);

}
private class GetCustomerDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        parseData(result);
    }
}


  // Given a URL, establishes an HttpUrlConnection and retrieves
 // the web page content as a InputStream, which it returns as
// a string.
private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    // Only display the first 500 characters of the retrieved
    // web page content.
    int len = 500;

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();

    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("cus_name", cus_names);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date1", createddate);
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("created_date2", created_date);



    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();

        // Convert the InputStream into a string
        String contentAsString = readIt(is, len);
        return contentAsString;

        // Makes sure that the InputStream is closed after the app is
        // finished using it.
    } finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }
}


public void parseData(String response){
    try {
        JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray data = parentObject.getJSONArray("customer_repo");

        //JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url,params));
        ArrayList<CustomerData> customerArrayList = new ArrayList<CustomerData>();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            String createdDate = c.getString("created_date");
            String orderNo = c.getString("created_date");
            customerArrayList.add(new CustomerData(createdDate, orderNo));
        }

        imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, customerArrayList);
        lisView1.setAdapter(imageAdapter);
        imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        registerForContextMenu(lisView1);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

   public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    ArrayList<CustomerData> customerDataArrayList;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,ArrayList<CustomerData>   customerDataArrayList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        context = c;
        this.customerDataArrayList= customerDataArrayList;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customerDataArrayList.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return customerDataArrayList.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_cus_report, null);
        }

        // created date
        TextView txtOrdDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColOrDate);
        txtOrdDate.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
        txtOrdDate.setText(customerDataArrayList.get(position).getCreatedAt() + ".");
        txtOrdDate.setTextSize(18);
        txtOrdDate.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        // Oredr No
        TextView txtOrdNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColOrNo);
        txtOrdNo.setPadding(5, 0, 0, 0);
        txtOrdNo.setText(customerDataArrayList.get(position).getOrderNo());
        txtOrdNo.setTextSize(18);
        txtOrdNo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

Post your **getJSONUrl** method aswell

Comment: first Thanks for Responce John. imageAdapter cannot resolve symbol Error @John

Comment: Move ImageAdapter to a new Java file and import it in this class and use

Comment: after create new java class file Customer_Repo_ImageAdapter and paste it. Still i am getting same error in imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, customerArrayList); @John

Comment: You may mis ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, customerArrayList);

Comment: its is there in parseData() method

Comment: Check out this doc for AsyncTaskUsage

Comment: You have to declare it...in the global variable.You can edit it if you want..@Karthiveture , Dont expect each line to be coded for you...we can give right guidance and help find mistakes.

Comment: what is happening now ?

Comment: I change the Code as per my requirement but i have some issue@john bro

Comment: Now i Edit my Question, I can Implement AsyncTask, I am face problem in passing values @John

Comment: You are using the Asynctask wrongly. You should return the result from doInBackground. Dont save it in Content and get it in OnPostExecute. And dont declare Views inside Asynctask. Check my answer and do according to that.

Comment: I have mentioned the problem  in the previous comment it self. Change according to that.

Comment: Uff...what is the error you  are getting. Check the logs. You should at least try to put some effort for debugging. Update your code in the question